# @Rollback(false) not working on @Before using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: spring, testing, junit, junit4, spring-test

In a JUnit test in my Spring application, I'd like to insert a lot of data in a setup method, and then use it to test against. However, whatever is done in the `@Before` method appears to be rolled back after each test, even if I annotate the method with `@Rollback(false)`

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class TestClass
{
   @Autowired 
   MyService service;

   @Before
   public void setup()
   {
      if(service.getById(1) == null)
      {
         Thing thing = new Thing();
         thing.setId(1);
         service.create(new Thing(1))
      }
   }
}
```

I've also tried using `@BeforeClass`,  but that requires the method to be static, and executes before any `@Autowired` setter methods are called, so I can't get access to the services I need to call when `@BeforeClass` runs.

I tried using `@PostConstruct`, but there are issues with having a transaction available (and my setup is such that a Hibernate session is only available when a transaction starts). Weirdly a session seemed to be available, but two objects got from within the same session were not equal, meaning Hibernate 1st-level cache seemed to be failing, or each operation was happening in a separate session. `@BeforeTransaction` seemed to exhibit the same behaviour.

Comment: Where did you put the `@Rollback` annotation, at class or method level?

Comment: @Ralph I've tried both on the `setup()` method `@Rollback(false)`, and then also on the class whilst also annotating test methods with `@Rollback`.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to achieve this?

Comment: @Arjan: I don't think so - I moved on to a new employer and so didn't have to deal with the same problem again.

Answer (score 2):

The Spring [TransactionalTestExecutionListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionalTestExecutionListener.html) is responsible for managing the transaction for the Junit Tests. It uses two methods (**beforeTestMethod** and **afterTestMethod**) to start and end the transaction for each of the Junit Tests.

As for @Before annotation it seems to work like this, It applies the **@Rollback attribute specified on the Test method to the to setUp method** with @Before annotation

I have this example to explain the process, I have two test methods one with (roll back false the other with roll back true)

```
      @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
      @ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes={SpringConfig.class})
      @Transactional
       public class MyTest 
      {

        @Before
        public void setUp()
        {
            //When executing this method setUp
            //The transaction will be rolled back after rollBackTrue Test
            //The transaction will not be rolled back after rollBackFalse Test
         }


        @Test
        @Rollback(true)
        public void rollBackTrue()
        {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }

        @Test
        @Rollback(false)
        public void rollBackFalse()
        {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Prasana. Thanks for your answer, but that can't be correct. If service.create() was not part of a transaction, then why is it by default being rolled back after every test? The problem is *want* it to be outside of a transaction so it will not get rolled back, but can't find out how.

Comment: Sorry, My Test threw me off and also I should have read the method documentation, I changed the answer with an example.