# How do you get the setup method in a test (with @Before) to not rollback, even when you have a test method (with @Test) set to rollback?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm doing some test data load inside the setup() method.
That is, I want this test data to be setup once and be available for all tests within the class.

However, a transaction test method (annotated with @Test and @Rollback(true), causes the setup method to rollback as well..

Is there a way to make sure that only the test method rolls back and not the setup?
Note :- Can't use @BeforeClass, as I need access to Autowired beans from spring context, which are not available in static context of setup(), if it's annotated as @BeforeClass.

Thanks,
Shekhar

---

PS : A similar question was asked in stackoverflow but never answered :-
[@Rollback(false) not working on @Before using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851341/rollbackfalse-not-working-on-before-using-springjunit4classrunner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@TestExecutionListener` instead of `@BeforeClass`. That way your test context will be loaded before execution. Furthermore, the setup code is externalised an can be reused for other tests.

More informations can be found here: [What is the difference between @BeforeClass and Spring @TestExecutionListener beforeTestClass()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404636/what-is-the-difference-between-beforeclass-and-spring-testexecutionlistener-be)

Comment: Can I access autowired beans within the beforeTestClass override, in the class that I extend from AbstractTestExecutionListener? Doesn't seem to work. All the autowired beans appear to be null..Hence, I can't use them to load the test data.

Comment: Guess, can't use @Autowired annotation.Would have to use - testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean("<bean-name>")